# How do I Make My created_at Timestamps set to the User timezone?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I have a React/Rails app that allows users to submit a report. However, the reports are always being marked with a utc created_at timestamp. Since the users are in different timezones this can cause a problem.

For example, if I create a report at ~9pm PST for February 7, the utc timestamp will show February 8 - which messed with daily reporting.

I thought this could mitigated on the front end, but using the javascript Date() object, which I thought would be local to the machine running the js, but the rails db timestamps still show the UTC time.

So far I've tried that, adding this in the createReport component

```
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!rep_type) {
      alert("Please provide a rep_type")
      return
    }
    const date = new Date();
    let data = await axios.post(`${API_ROOT}/api/reports`, {
      report: {
        user_id: props.currentUser.id,
        rep_type: rep_type,
        rep_count: rep_count,
        created_at: date
      }
    })
```

And then in my reports_controller.rb I am expecting created_at to be a parameter

```
  def create
    @report = Report.create!(
      user_id: params["report"]["user_id"],
      rep_type: params["report"]["rep_type"],
      rep_count: params["report"]["rep_count"],
      created_at: params["report"]["date"]
    )
  end
```

What's interesting, is when I console.log(date) I see what I'd expect:

```
Mon Feb 07 2022 18:15:52 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

But when I look at the network request I see the date is back to UTC

[image: utc?]

Edit:

By changing my POST request in createReport to send date as a string I can see in the network request I am sending the date/timezone I want, but rails is automatically changing it to UTC so I think it's a rails thing to fix.

What would be the most straightforward approach to make sure the date is at least accurate to the date in which the user created the report?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to ask the user to select the timezone that he/she wants to use in the system and then in a `around_action` I set the timezone for the request. In that way all dates are saved in UTC but are visible in the user's timezone

```rb
around_action :set_time_zone
...
def set_time_zone
  old_time_zone = Time.zone
  Time.zone = current_user.timezone
  yield
ensure
  Time.zone = old_time_zone
end
```

Another option is to send the offset (not the date) from the browser and set the `Time.zone` based on that

```js
const date = new Date();
const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

and then in rails

```rb
Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-offset]
```

But, it could be tricky for DST

My advice is to keep the timestamps as UTC in the database and only transform it to show to the user, for reporting just be careful doing the searches using times that include timezones